# Wrapping SharedPreferences with Dagger 2 and RxJava2

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, dagger-2, rx-java2

Do I need to wrap the Android `SharedPreferences` class or not? If yes, can you please provide me a simple working example?

I know how to use the `SharedPreferences`, but when it comes to wrapping it and providing it with Dagger 2 and RxJava2 I am confused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually just wrap it using an interface called `LocalStorage` or something similar. Then inject a `Context` into the implementation and implement your SharedPreferences as usual. If you want to use Rx just make sure your interface methods return `Observables`.

Then whenever you need to use SharedPeferences just have a `LocalStorage` injected and you're all set.

Edit: Im not sure how much code you need but here's a sample.

Start off by defining an interface

```
public interface LocalStorage {
    void writeMessage(String message);
    Observable<String> readMessage();
}
```

Then write the implementation of this interface using SharedPreferences. So what do we need for this to work? Well, all we really need is a `Context`, but let's not worry about that, we will pass one through the constructor when we create the `LoginStorage` in the dagger 2 module.

```
public class SharedPrefStorage implements LocalStorage {

    private Context context;

    public SharedPrefStorage(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeMessage(String message) {
        context.getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit().putString("myMessage", message).apply();
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<String> readMessage() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return context.getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString("myMessage", "");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you see we simply read and write the values as usual, nothing fancy. Now we just add this to our Dagger 2 AppModule (or whatever you decided to call it). We already know that we will need a Context for the SharedPrefStorage to work, so put it as a parameter and dagger will inject it (provided you have a @Provides method with a context, for example your application class).

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private MyApplication app;

    public AppModule(MyApplication app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public MyApplication provideApp() {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public LocalStorage provideLocalStorage(MyApplication context)
        return new SharedPrefStorage(context);
    }
}
```

And then, of course, let's add it to our Dagger 2 component so that we actually expose the LocalStorage and can have it injected wherever we want it.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    LocalStorage localStorage();
}
```

Now we can just have our LocalStorage injected whenever we need one. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: can u give a raw sample for it?

Comment: Btw, you have a typo in the title. You might want to change that so that people with the same problem can find this thread.

Comment: I'm curious if it's any benefits using the interface LocalStorage here since it only has one implementation?

Comment: If you have to change the implementation to say a SQL database in the future the refactoring will be a lot less painful since you can just implement the interface and inject the new implementation. Every usage of LocalStorage can be untouched and will work the same. But no, in theory you don't have to use the interface